# Use the category node name as a label in Zikula

Tags: symfony, twig, zikula

I do use Zikula 1.5.2dev

My module is generated with modulestudio

I have made two entries in the Category registry. One is showing at the node "Global" and one at the node "Type"

In Global are several entries I can select. Some other entries are inside Type.

The selection is working in my template like expected. But how can I use the node names as a label?

I can not figure out in which template I have to place to label (have to do more searching). But more important, I do not know the right twig syntax to catch the categories label.

Answer (score 0):

if you assign a category to the template, the properties are accessible like normal class properties.

```
{{ category.name }}
```

if you need the display name, this is stored as an array with lang codes as keys

```
{{ category.display_name['de'] }}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds good. But now I have recognized this label seem not to be placed in a pure template. There is a form type defined:

```
class ShowRoomItemType extends AbstractShowRoomItemType
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function addCategoriesField(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('categories', CategoriesType::class, [
            'label' => $this->__('Category') . ':',
            'empty_data' => null,
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'category-selector'
            ],
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
            'module' => 'RKShowRoomModule',
            'entity' => 'ShowRoomItemEntity',
            'entityCategoryClass' => 'RK\ShowRoomModule\Entity\ShowRoomItemCategoryEntity',
            // added:
            'includeGrandChildren' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my template it is called like this:

```
{{ form_row(quickNavForm.categories) }}
```

For this my skills are very limmited. I will write a feature request at modulestudio. (https://github.com/Guite/MostGenerator/issues/1147)

But big thanks for your reply!

Comment: Feature is integrated. I now tested it. It is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed for core 1.5.4 / 2.0.4 in https://github.com/zikula/core/pull/3846